# How to make this cumulative sum with divide and conquer faster with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, divide-and-conquer

This is my code for calculate cumulative sum of a list using divide and conquer.
input: [1,2,3,4,5]
output: [1,3,6,10,15]

I tried to make it faster by using ProcessPoolExecutor but the result shows that multiprocessing is slower than single processing.
Could you please explain me why multiprocessing is slower than single processing and how to improve my multiprocessing code to make it faster than single processing by using pure Python code and divide and conquer approach, not using 3rd library.
Thank you.

Single processing:

```
def cum_sum_dac(lst,new_lst,count):

    if len(lst)==1:
        n=lst[0]
        # print('n=',n)
        new_lst[n-1]=(n*(n+1)/2)
    else:
        count[0]+=1
        mid=len(lst)//2
        first_half=lst[:mid]
        second_half=lst[mid:]
        cum_sum_dac(first_half,new_lst,count)
        cum_sum_dac(second_half,new_lst, count)
```

Multi-processing with ProcessPoolExecutor:

```
def cum_sum_dac_multi(lst,new_lst,count):
    if len(lst)==1:
        n=lst[0]
        # print('n=',n)
        new_lst[n-1]=(n*(n+1)/2)
    else:
        count[0]+=1
        mid=len(lst)//2
        first_half=lst[:mid]
        second_half=lst[mid:]
        if count[0]<4:
            with Pool(2) as pool:
                pool.map(cum_sum_dac_multi,[first_half, second_half],[new_lst,new_lst],[count, count])
        else:
            cum_sum_dac_multi(first_half,new_lst,count)
            cum_sum_dac_multi(second_half,new_lst, count)
```

This is my full code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def cum_sum_dac(lst,new_lst,count):
    if len(lst)==1:
        n=lst[0]
        # print('n=',n)
        new_lst[n-1]=(n*(n+1)/2)
    else:
        count[0]+=1
        mid=len(lst)//2
        first_half=lst[:mid]
        second_half=lst[mid:]
        cum_sum_dac_multi(first_half,new_lst,count)
        cum_sum_dac_multi(second_half,new_lst, count)
    

def cum_sum_dac_multi(lst,new_lst,count):
    if len(lst)==1:
        n=lst[0]
        # print('n=',n)
        new_lst[n-1]=(n*(n+1)/2)
    else:
        count[0]+=1
        mid=len(lst)//2
        first_half=lst[:mid]
        second_half=lst[mid:]
        if count[0]<4:
            with Pool(2) as pool:
                pool.map(cum_sum_dac_multi,[first_half, second_half],[new_lst,new_lst],[count, count])
        else:
            cum_sum_dac_multi(first_half,new_lst,count)
            cum_sum_dac_multi(second_half,new_lst, count)
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    # Multiprocessing
    count=[0]
    st = time.process_time()
    a=[x for x in range(1,100000)]
    man = mp.Manager()
    cum_list=man.list(range(1,100000))
    cum_sum_dac_multi(a,cum_list,count)
    # print(cum_list)
    et = time.process_time()
    # get execution time
    res_multi = et - st
    print("sum multi=",a,'CPU Execution time:', res_multi*1000, 'millis')
    #-------------------------------------------------------
    # Single processing
    count=[0]
    st = time.process_time()
    a=[x for x in range(1,100000)]
    man = mp.Manager()
    cum_list=man.list(range(1,100000))
    cum_sum_dac(a,cum_list,count)
    # print(cum_list)
    et = time.process_time()
    # get execution time
    res = et - st
    print("sum =",a,'CPU Execution time:', res*1000, 'millis')
    print(f"multiprocess is {(res-res_multi)*1000} millis faster")
```

Comment: `numpy.cumsum(a)` would likely get faster results ...

Comment: Thank you but I want to do it without 3rd library for deep understanding.

Comment: Due to overhead, Python using multiple processes for simple computations is slower than a single process.

Comment: Multiprocessing is good at doing two **independent** things at once, but if they require sharing memory via a `mp.Manager`, each side is going to have to serialize data and send it through a pipe whenever the data changes, which I would guess is causing the slowdown

Comment: [muliprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory) may be a faster way to share data without serailizing it repeatedly

Comment: Both algorithms are not divide-and-conquer ones, so it's meaningless to compare them.(They don't utilize solutions of small(divided) problems to solve the big problem. ```n*(n+1)/2``` Huh)